# Implementing Exception Handling ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Java

Tags: java, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

This is a homework problem.

Here is an example of a maze I am solving:

6 6
5 0 5 5 5 5
5 0 0 0 0 5
5 5 0 5 0 5
5 5 0 5 5 5
5 0 0 0 0 0
5 5 5 5 5 5
4 5

EDIT: There is no error in my program. My professor wants me to find the maze exit by catching the ArrayIndexoutOfBoundsException

I was tasked with writing a program to read a file and put all of the numbers into a 2D array. I am given the starting point and was told to write a program that navigates its way through the maze by adding coordinates onto a stack. 
It moves to one coordinate in the array and checks coordinates in a clockwise direction to see if there is a potential move. 
I have the program working smoothly and outputting correctly.

However, today in class, my professor said that we must catch the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in our program.

I originally just created a method to check if the coordinates I want to look at exist and are inside the array.

My question is is there an easy way to implement exception handling into the code I already have?

I don't have any experience handling exceptions and everything I see when I research is used just to print out a string saying that there was an error.

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import stackpackage.*;
public class mazeDriver {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File inputFile = new File("maze1.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    int rows = getRows(in);
    int columns = getColumns(in);
    int[][]maze = createMaze(in, rows, columns);
    int sRow = getSRow(in);
    int sColumn = getSColumn(in);
    Coordinate start = new Coordinate(sRow, sColumn);
    in.close();
    GoodStack stack = new GoodStack();
    GoodStack answerStack = mazeRunner(start, maze, stack, columns, rows);
    coursePrint(answerStack);
}
public static int getRows(Scanner in){
    int rows = in.nextInt();
    return rows;
}
public static int getColumns(Scanner in){
    int columns = in.nextInt();
    return columns;
}
public static int[][] createMaze(Scanner in, int rows, int columns){
    int[][]maze = new int[rows][columns];
    int rowAccumulator = 0;
    int columnAccumulator = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= (rows*columns)-1; i++){
        int value = in.nextInt();
        maze[rowAccumulator][columnAccumulator] = value;
        if (columnAccumulator == columns - 1){
            columnAccumulator = 0;
            rowAccumulator += 1;
        }
        else{
            columnAccumulator += 1;
            }
        }
        return maze;
        }
public static int getSRow(Scanner in){
    int sRow = in.nextInt();
    return sRow;
    }
public static int getSColumn(Scanner in){
    int sColumn = in.nextInt();
    return sColumn;
    }

/*
This method is what searches through the maze in a clockwise direction.
@param The starting point coordinates, the 2d array of the maze, the empty             stack, and the maze size
@return The stack of coordinates to navigate the maze
**/
public static GoodStack mazeRunner(Coordinate startingPoint, int[][]array,      GoodStack stack, int columns, int rows){
    array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()] = 1; // Sets   the starting coordinate to 1
    stack.push(startingPoint); // Adds the point to the stack
    boolean finish = false; // Sets the value to false until the maze is   finished
    int skipFirst = 0; // this is a counter I used so that it does not exit on it's first run

while(finish ==  false){ // Create a loop to run until the maze has been finished
    if(inBounds(startingPoint.getRow()-1, startingPoint.getColumn(), rows, columns)){ // checks if the array location is in the array
        if (array[startingPoint.getRow()-1][startingPoint.getColumn()] == 0){ // checks if the value of that location is 0.
            Coordinate location = new Coordinate(startingPoint.getRow()-1 , startingPoint.getColumn()); // creates a coordinate instance of the location
            stack.push(location);// pushes the location onto the stack
            array[startingPoint.getRow()-1][startingPoint.getColumn()] = 1; // sets the array value to 1 for that location
            startingPoint = location; // makes the location the next search point
            skipFirst +=1; // adds to the counter
            continue;}} // skips the rest of the loop and moves on to the next iteration
    // The next three if statements have the same effect as the last one, the only difference being it checks in the other three directions
    if(inBounds(startingPoint.getRow(),startingPoint.getColumn() + 1, rows, columns)){  
        if(array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()+1] == 0){
            Coordinate location = new Coordinate(startingPoint.getRow(), startingPoint.getColumn()+ 1);
            stack.push(location);
            array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn() + 1] = 1;
            startingPoint = location;
            skipFirst +=1;
            continue;}}


    if(inBounds(startingPoint.getRow()+1, startingPoint.getColumn(), rows, columns)){   
        if(array[startingPoint.getRow()+1][startingPoint.getColumn()] == 0){
            Coordinate location = new Coordinate(startingPoint.getRow()+1, startingPoint.getColumn());
            stack.push(location);
            array[startingPoint.getRow()+1][startingPoint.getColumn()] = 1;
            startingPoint = location;
            skipFirst +=1;
            continue;}}


    if(inBounds(startingPoint.getRow(),startingPoint.getColumn()-1, rows, columns)){        
        if(array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()-1] == 0){
            Coordinate location = new Coordinate(startingPoint.getRow(), startingPoint.getColumn()-1);
            stack.push(location);
            array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()-1] = 1;
            startingPoint = location;
            skipFirst +=1;
            continue;}}
    if(mazeExit(startingPoint.getRow(), startingPoint.getColumn(), rows, columns)){ // Checks to see if there is a potential exit
        if(skipFirst>2){ // This makes sure that it does not exit the maze from the entry
            finish = true; // Sets the boolean to true to stop the while loop
            return stack;}} // And returns the stack of coordinates
     // This  code happens only if it does not find any 0's to travel to    
    array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()] = 1; // sets the space it is on to 1
    stack.pop(); // removes the space from the stack 
    Coordinate nextStart = (Coordinate)stack.peek(); // takes the top coordinate off of the stack
    startingPoint = nextStart; // sets the top coordinate to the starting search point
}

return stack;
}

/*
This method checks the coordinates that are about to be check to see if they are inside the array
@param The row and column that is being checked and the size of the array
@return boolean value
**/
public static boolean inBounds(int row, int column, int arrayRow, int  arrayColumn){
    boolean result = false;
    if (row <= arrayRow -1 && row >= 0 && column <= arrayColumn-1 && column  >= 0){ // checks to see if the coordinate is in the array
    result = true;}
    return result;
 }
 /*
This method is what searches through the maze in a clockwise direction.
@param The starting point coordinates, the 2d array of the maze, the empty  stack, and the maze size
@return The stack of coordinates to navigate the maze
**/
public static boolean mazeExit(int row, int column, int arrayRow, int    arrayColumn){
    boolean result = false;
    // This method checks all four directions to see if there is a potential  exit
    if(row == arrayRow-1){
        result = true;}
    if(column == arrayColumn-1){
        result = true;}
    if(row == 0){
        result = true;}
    if(column == 0){
        result = true;}

    return result;}
/*
This method reverses the order of the coordinates and prints it out.
@param The stack of coordinates
**/
public static void coursePrint(GoodStack stack){
    List<Coordinate> list = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(); // Creates an empty  arraylist
    while(stack.isEmpty() == false){
        Coordinate myObject = (Coordinate)stack.pop(); // takes the top    coordinate from the array
        list.add(myObject); // and adds it into the array list
    }
        Collections.reverse(list); // Reverses the order of the arraylist
    for(Coordinate i:list){
        System.out.println(i);} // Prints out every coordinate in the array list
}

}
```

Comment: which line gives the erroor?

Comment: Google "java try catch exception".  It's not that difficult really.

Comment: To answer your question, you should look into try/catch exceptions that would catch the arrayindexoutofbounds error

Comment: You should NOT catch an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. If such an exception is thrown, it means you have a bug in your code, and didn't check for array boundaries correctly. The solution is to fix the code, not to catch the exception. If your teacher really advised to catch such an exception (rather than **preventing** it), then that's terrible advice.

Comment: Include the stack trace. It will show you which line is throwing the exception. It's either happening when you create the array or are trying to read or modify it.  On that note, why aren't you using a nested loop to populate the array. Your method looks like it could easily step out of the bounds of the array size.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear, there is no error in my code. It works fine. However, my professor wants me to find the exit to the maze, by catching an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: @Abdelhak My code does not give an error. I am supposed to catch the error.

Comment: @JBNizet My code does not give throw an error. I think what he was going for was wanting me to catch an OOB exception to find the exit to the maze. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must end program with catching exception even though your program works correctly (which i think is stupid, but ok), then you could do something like this:

if you check for exit only if the location is out of bounds(mazeExit method), then you could just add to your stack locations that point to outside of bounds and replace

```
if(mazeExit(startingPoint.getRow(), startingPoint.getColumn(), rows, columns)){ // Checks to see if there is a potential exit
        if(skipFirst>2){ // This makes sure that it does not exit the maze from the entry
            finish = true; // Sets the boolean to true to stop the while loop
            return stack;}} // And returns the stack of coordinates
     // This  code happens only if it does not find any 0's to travel to    
    array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()] = 1; // sets the      space it is on to 1
```

with

```
try{
     // This  code happens only if it does not find any 0's to travel to    
    array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()] = 1; // sets the space it is on to 1
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  e) {
    // Checks to see if there is a potential exit
    if (skipFirst>2) { // This makes sure that it does not exit the maze from the entry
        finish = true; // Sets the boolean to true to stop the while loop
        return stack;
    } // And returns the stack of coordinates
}
```

What this will do is when you get to a location that is outside bounds, then this will trigger Exception because of array[startingPoint.getRow()][startingPoint.getColumn()] and then it will execute catch block. But be careful with having an if in your catch, because if your if code won't execute, then you need to be aware that you won't set value in array to 1 and you won't exit the program, so watch out what happens next.

But again, it is usually not a good practice to force catching exceptions if you don't have, if you don't have a good reason to.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer man I really appreciate it! I have a bit of an egotistical professor so it is his way or the highway! I will implement this and get  back to you!